# Cannot open default layouts on Eclipse after creating small version of each of them

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout

Sooo... I've come across a rather odd issue...
I am creating an app and need different versions of the layout for different devices. The default layout was made for my Nexus 7, so you can imagine it is quite large.

As recommended by the documentation, I created a layout-small folder in which I designed every Activity layout for a small device. So far so good, everything goes smoothly. I decide to change some buttons on my default layout as it will look better, but whenever I try to open it, it's display is of the 2.7''QVGA and whenever I try to change it back to the Nexus 7, Eclipse opens up my file from the layout-small folder! Damn it Eclipse! Let me choose what I open! When I run it, it still looks fine but this issue isn't allowing me to make any changes on what I have!

I already tried closing it and everything, but the damn small version of the layout keeps opening, over the default one!

Hope the issue is clear enough... I can see how it would be hard to understand.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, try letting the os know what sizes are supported by adding:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

Once you have this in your manifest, you can also use it to switch the use of various sizes on and off by toggling between true and false, to help test and debug your code.

Also, make sure that the changes you've made to your default layout are valid. If the changes make your default xml un-useable then one of the others may be used instead.